# Why the second dimension in a Numpy array is empty?

Tags: numpy, dimensions

Why the output here

```
array = np.arange(3)
array.shape
```

is

```
(3,)
```

and not

```
(1,3)
```

What does the missing dimension means or equals?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html has examples.  why don't you try np.arange(3) versus np.arange(3).reshape(1, 3) to see the visual differences

Comment: @NaN the reshape will change it to (1, 3), but why the original array is not (1,3)?

Comment: That is covered in the docs

Comment: The link you provided just shows some examples and doesn't explain why

Comment: You are creating a vector which by definition is only one dimension, not two.

Comment: np.arange(3).ndim  # 1 ...

np.arange(3).reshape(1, 3).ndim  # 2 … 

np.arange(3).reshape(3, 1).ndim  #  2

Comment: @David there is no concept of "vector" in numpy. You have `numpy.ndarray` objects, which are n-dimensional arrays, where n can be any non negative integer.

Comment: Yes, numoy creates ndarrays, but the real world mathematical equivalent is a vector which can be useful to point out, especially for people coming in not knowing numpy.

Comment: @David then your comment simply doesn't make sense, since the question is about numpy, and there is no such definition

Comment: Or, is simply tautological, equivalent to "your array is one dimensional because you created a one dimensional array" which wouldn't be *wrong*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, it is tautological as what they are asking boils down to "why does the one dimensional array that I have created only have one dimension?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case there's confusion, `(3,)` doesn't mean there's a missing dimension.  The comma is part of the standard Python notation for a single element tuple.  Shapes `(1,3), (3,), and (3,1)` are distinct,

While they can contain the same 3 elements, their use in calculations (`broadcasting`) is different, their print format is different, and their list equivalent is different:

```
In [21]: np.array([1,2,3])
Out[21]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [22]: np.array([1,2,3]).tolist()
Out[22]: [1, 2, 3]
In [23]: np.array([1,2,3]).reshape(1,3).tolist()
Out[23]: [[1, 2, 3]]
In [24]: np.array([1,2,3]).reshape(3,1).tolist()
Out[24]: [[1], [2], [3]]
```

And we don't have to stop at adding just one singleton dimension:

```
In [25]: np.array([1,2,3]).reshape(1,3,1).tolist()
Out[25]: [[[1], [2], [3]]]
In [26]: np.array([1,2,3]).reshape(1,3,1,1).tolist()
Out[26]: [[[[1]], [[2]], [[3]]]]
```

---

In `numpy` an array can have 0, 1, 2 or more dimensions.  1 dimension is just as logical as 2.

In MATLAB a matrix always has 2 dim (or more), but it doesn't have to be that way.   Strictly speaking MATLAB doesn't even have scalars.  An array with shape (3,) is missing a dimension only if MATLAB is taken as the standard.

`numpy` is built on Python which as scalars, and lists (which can nest).  How many dimensions does a Python list have?

If you want to get into history, MATLAB was developed as a front end to a set of Fortran linear algebra routines.  Given the problems those routines solved the concept of matrix with 2 dimensions, and row vs column vectors made sense.  It wasn't until version 3.something that MATLAB was generalized to allow more than 2 dimensions (in the late 1990s).

`numpy` is based on several attempts to provide arrays to Python (e.g. `numeric`).  Those developers took a more general approach to arrays, one where 2d was an artificial constraint.  That has precedence in computer languages and mathematics (and physics). APL was developed in the 1960s, first as a mathematical notation, and then as a computer language.  Like `numpy` its `arrays` can be 0d or higher.  (Since I used APL before I used MATLAB, the `numpy` approach feels quite natural.)

---

In `APL` there aren't separate lists or tuples.  So the shape of an `array`, `rho A` is itself an array, and `rho rho A` is the number of dimensions of A, also called the `rank`.

http://docs.dyalog.com/14.0/Dyalog%20APL%20Idioms.pdf

Comment: I would say Python has various *containers*, and the concept of scalars doesn't really apply. And lists don't have dimensions :)

Comment: This answer really isn't an answer to what they are saying and would be better served being a comment.

Comment: @David, I started to write a comment, and then decided it was too long for that.  This issue has been hashed out many times, and probably should be closed as a duplicate, or may be a matter of opinion.

Comment: @David this answers the question, insofar as I can make sense of the OPs question