# Why does numpy not produce '2D' arrays of well defined dimensions for basic functionalities such as np.random.uniform etc

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have used python before, but for some reason did not notice this issue. In the present code I am writing, I am often needing to produce arrays using the numpy modules:

-`np.random.uniform(0,1,n)` or `np.random.normal(0,0.1,n)`

-`np.asarray([1,2,3])`

However I was having trouble combining these with other operations, for example matrix multiplication. Using `np.shape()`, I found that the output of these is `(n,)`, `(3,)` i.e. they have undefined second dimension.

My questions are:

1. Why is this the case? Is it at all useful in any situations? Why not make it `(n,1)`?
2. I am presently constantly using `numpy.reshape()` to turn a shape `(n,)` to `(n,1)`. Is there a way to produce these arrays with a correct shape straight away?

Comment: Yes. Pass in the correct shape... Are you asking how to use the `size` argument? Please read the docs for the functions you want to use.

Comment: `(3,)` is not any sort of "undefined second dimension", that's simply how a 1-element tuple is written in Python.  (`(3)` would just be a parenthesized number.)

Comment: @jasonharper Tuple? But I am using asarray! OK if I misunderstood the output from the random number generators and it is indeed a tuple rather than array, but np.asarray should surely produce an array, so a second dimension should be stated?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/51334276/901925

Comment: The shape of an numpy array is represented as a tuple.  `np.asarray([1,2,3])` is quite explicitly creating a 1-dimensional array, so its shape tuple contains one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/284995/are-1-dimensional-numpy-arrays-equivalent-to-vectors) may explain the difference.

The variable with shape `(n,)` is a vector. Its transpose also has the same shape. However, the variable with shape `(n,1)` is a 1-dimensional array in which the transpose will have the shape `(1,n)`

2. You can use `a = np.asmatrix([1,2,3]).T` to get array of shape `(n,1)`

Answer (score 0):

Why not make an array with shape (n,) to (n,1) ?

```py
a = np.arange(0, 10)
print(a.shape) # (10,)
print(a[0]) # 0

b = a.reshape([-1, 1])
print(b.shape) # (10, 1)
print(b[0]) # array([0])
```

`a[0]` returns a single value and `b[0]` returns an array instead (with 1 element) because it has 2 dimensions

---

> Is there a way to produce these arrays with a correct shape straight
>   away?

```py
np.random.uniform(1, 10, size=(10,1))
np.asarray([1,2,3])[:, np.newaxis]
```